# Unable to add new zone/domain in PowerDNS using API

Tags: powerdns

I was trying to add new zone using following:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"name":"saugat.local", "kind": "Master","dnssec":false,"soa-edit":"INCEPTION-INCREMENT","masters": [], "nameservers": ["ns1.saugat.local"]}' -v -H 'X-API-Key: changeme' http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v1/servers/localhost/zones | jq .
```

I was expecting, I'll add new zone but I got following error:

"error": "DNS Name 'saugat.local' is not canonical"

[Error Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uus4C.png)

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a trailing dot to make the domain in canonical shape

```
curl -X POST --data '{"name":"saugat.local.", "kind": "Master","dnssec":false,"soa-edit":"INCEPTION-INCREMENT","masters": [], "nameservers": ["ns1.saugat.local."]}' -v -H 'X-API-Key: changeme' http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v1/servers/localhost/zones | jq .
```

Comment: this also gives me the following error:

{
  "error": "Nameserver is not canonical: 'ns1.saugat.local'"
}

Comment: Just fixed the payload, as the nameserver also needs to be in canonical shape